# HTML and Javascript code issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have created two HTML pages, one is called *username.html* and the other -- resume.html.

What I want to do is, that no matter which page I open, I'll be always redirected to login page. If I open the *username.html*, it will be opened up and I fill in the username and password fields, then the *resume.html* opens.

Here is my code of login page:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <title>Login page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;text-align:center;font-size:50pt;color:#ff00ba;">
            You need to login :)
        </h1>     

        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <form style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;">
                Username<br>
                <input type="text" name="userid"/><br>
                Password<br>
                <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
                <br><br>
                <input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" onclick="check(form)" value="Login"/>
                <input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
                <input style="font-family:Comic Sans Ms;" type="button" value="Log out" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedIn');location.href='/username.html'"/>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script language="javascript">
            function check(form){
                if(form.userid.value == "pwan9047" && form.pswrd.value == "Wang1984"){
                    localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',true);location.href='/resume.html';
                }else{
                    alert("Error Password or Username")
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also added the following JS code to the *resume.html* to let it direct to username.html when the *resume.html* is opened:

```
<script>
    window.onload=function(){
        if(localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')==null){
            location.href="/username.html";
        }
    }
</script>
```

It works fine with my html editor (I am using Brackets as the editor), however, when I just click on the html files on my folder, there is a problem with it, the login page does not direct to resume page after I correctly fill the username and password, it shows page not found, the url is *"file:///C:/resume.html"*, also when I click logout button, it has the same thing that page not found, the url is *"file:///C:/username.html"*.

Thanks

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: Hi jojo, my folder has resume.html. username.html and resume.css, I put the folder in my desktop

Comment: @user4696819 — That's the problem then. Your URLs don't point to a folder on your desktop. They point to the local root.

Comment: exactly Quentin, when I use the editor to open the pages, the url showed my localhost address whereas when I opened the html file directly, it showed the C drive's location of the file, this is the difference I found and may be also the issue, so how can I make the change then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
location.href="/username.html";
```

You started the href with a forward slash ( / )
This means that the url is relative to the website root.
In brackets, your site runs in a localhost server, like http://localhost:xxxxx. This root url is indeed the folder with your website, but when you open it via your normal filesystem (file:///), the root is your **C drive** (file:///C:/)
Your file isn't directly in the c drive? Or is it?
If you plan to publish your site to a webserver, you shouldn't worry, because this works the same as in brackets, and you will just go to your site root (like `/public_html/`)

If you really want to fix this just for opening it via the normal filesystem, you should use a relative href to the file, not a relative one to the root.
Just remove that forward slash to do this.

```
location.href="username.html";
```

Now, you start navigating from the folder where the current file is, so if you want to navigate from `website/index.html` to `website/subfolder/file2.html`, you can just do this using

```
href="subfolder/file2.html
```

Note that navigating from `website/subfolder/file2.html` to `website/index.html` won't work anymore, because there is no folder called 'website' inside 'subfolder'
You will need to navigate down, like this:

```
href="../file2.html"
```

`../` only navigates down **one folder**, so if you want to navigate down two folders (for example from a subfolder inside a subfolder to something in the root) you can use two of them

```
href="../../file2.html"
```

Comment: Hi jojo, one more thing to mention, when I remove the slash in front of the file, it is still working with Brackets, which is opened via website root in localhost, I thought it can be only accessed via root by having the slash

Comment: No slash means start in the same folder as current file, so if both files are in the site root, yes. Note that if you are navigating from a subfolder to the root, you can go down one folder by using '../file.html' @user4696819

Comment: I see, so I want to still use slash in front of the file, can I just move to my html files to C drive without any subfolder? such as C:/resume.html and C:/username.html

Comment: Read my edit, it might help you out @user4696819. Moving files directly to the c drive won't be a great idea in my opinion...